# Next VC is not showing

Tags: ios, swift

I have a segue going from the first VC `clubSelectionViewController` to the one shown below `clubSummaryViewController`, but I have to click back 2 times to get the next VC to show. What am I doing wrong?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class clubSelectionViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {
    var clubsForSelection = [clubObject]()
    var clubForClubSummaryView = [clubObject]()

    @IBAction func selectDanceClubs(sender: AnyObject) {
        clubForClubSummaryView = clubDataFilter.removeStripClubsFrom(clubsForSelection)

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ClubSummary", sender: self)
    }

    @IBAction func selectStripClubs(sender: AnyObject) {
        clubForClubSummaryView = clubDataFilter.removeDanceClubsFrom(clubsForSelection)

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ClubSummary", sender: self)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // everytime screen loads it removes information to give blank screen it removes all clubs in array
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "ClubSummary" {
            let summaryView = segue.destinationViewController as! clubSummaryViewController
            summaryView.clubDetails = [clubObject]()
            summaryView.clubDetails = self.clubForClubSummaryView
        }
    }
}
```

Second VC

```
import UIKit

class clubSummaryViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    var clubDetails = [clubObject]()
    var selectedClub = clubObject()

    @IBOutlet var clubSummaryTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Declare Delegate, Load TableView
        clubSummaryTableView.delegate = self
        //clubSummaryTableView.dataSource = self
        clubSummaryTableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //MARK: TableViewDelegate

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
         return self.clubDetails.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell =  self.clubSummaryTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SummaryCell")! as? clubSummaryCell

        cell?.clubName.text = clubDetails[indexPath.row].clubName
        cell?.clubAddress.text = clubDetails[indexPath.row].clubAddress

        //TODO: insert image
        cell?.clubPhoto.image = clubDetails[indexPath.row].clubImage.image

        return cell!
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        self.selectedClub = self.clubDetails[indexPath.row]

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ClubDetails", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "ClubDetails"{
            let clubDetailsView = segue.destinationViewController as? clubInfoViewController
            clubDetailsView?.clubForDetails = self.selectedClub     
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Presumably you have 3 VCs - selection, summary, details. Are you asking why you have go press `back` twice to go from details to selection? Or are you saying touching `back` in summary does nothing the first time, but the second time takes you back to selection?

Comment: @Michael I have to press back twice from the summaryVC to selectionVC before the summaryVC actually shows everything its supposed to.

Comment: issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in the:

```
@IBAction func selectDanceClubs(sender: AnyObject) {
    clubForClubSummaryView = clubDataFilter.removeStripClubsFrom(clubsForSelection)

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ClubSummary", sender: self)
}

@IBAction func selectStripClubs(sender: AnyObject) {
    clubForClubSummaryView = clubDataFilter.removeDanceClubsFrom(clubsForSelection)

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ClubSummary", sender: self)
}
```

I not sure why you want these two func have the same SegueWithIdentifier

Comment: I have 2 buttons on one VC going to the same VC. They work its just the clubSummaryVC doesn't show at first. I have to go back a couple of times before clubSummaryVC works.

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be that you have attached the segue from the button itself.

That means when you click on button the segue from the button is getting called, and since you have action of the button also, the segue is called again from the action method.

Means, the same segue is called twice.

Comment: I only have one segue connected from the selectionVC to the summaryVC.

Comment: Is the segue is connected to button?